# C function fopen(); error: too many arguments to the function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, fopen

Why can I not do this?

```c
fopen("%s",stringarray,fpointer);
```

The above returns an error that says too many arguments to function.

But this works,

```c
fopen("file.txt",fpointer);
```

How can I get around this problem? Do I have to modify the headers in the code?

Comment: What type is `stringarray`?

Comment: char stringarray [32];

Comment: There seems to be some misconception here about how C functions work in general. Are you aware that `printf()` (the one where you'd work with `"%s"`) is pretty special, and that *not all functions work like this*? Why would you want to call `fopen("%s", stringarray, fpointer)` in the first place? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: program where user enters file name to be created

Comment: printf style format specifiers are not an intrinsic part of the language, format strings are parsed by the function itself at run-time, not by the compiler.  They are used for formatted output or input; that is turning data of one form to or from a string representation for _presentation_.  That is entirely irrelevant here.  You don;t need to "get around this problem" because there is no problem, other that your understanding of some fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `stringarray` is a `char *` (really a `chararray`), simply pass it directly into `fopen`. There's no need to format it with `%s`, it's already a string.

```
FILE *fp = fopen(stringarray, "r");
```

Functions in C take very, very, very specific arguments. [`fopen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen) takes a filename as a `char *` and the mode to open the file (read, write, etc...) as another `char *`. It returns a pointer to the opened file, or NULL if there was an error.

---

If you did need to do some sort of formatting, you'd use [`sprintf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf) to do the formatting and pass the result into [`fopen`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen).

```
// Allocate memory to store the result of sprintf
char filename[256];
char name[] = "foo";

// filename = foo.txt
sprintf(filename, "%s.txt", name);

// Open foo.txt
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call

```
fopen("%s",stringarray,fpointer);
```

because that's not the way `fopen` works.  You don't get to make up the way you want to call a standard function like this -- you have to call it the way [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) says to.  You can't call

```
 fopen("file.txt",fpointer);
```

either.  You have to call something like

```
fpointer = fopen("file.txt", "r");
```

assuming that you have declared

```
FILE *fpointer;
```

so that `fpointer` will be your "open file pointer" or "file handle" as you read the file `file.txt`.

Comment: Anyway I can get around this problem? Like other functions that work the way I want in other libraries or headers ( I need to use a string array that the user inputs as the file name)

Comment: It's easy to get around this problem -- just read [the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) for `fopen` and call it properly.  (Or reread my updated answer.)

Comment: But in general, please don't try to learn C by trial and error.  Here are [some class notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx12.html) you can read on opening and reading files properly.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
fopen (const char *filename, const char *mode)
```

If you take a look in `fopen` function, it takes only two arguments as input. So, you cannot use it like `fopen("%s",stringarray,fpointer);`. For more information about `fopen()` visit [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen)